# In C, is a declaration of an extern function that excludes a const/restrict qualifier equivalent to the original declaration?

Tags: c

For instance, `fwrite` has the following signature:

```c
size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

If I were to declare:

```c
size_t fwrite(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

(leaving out the const),

is it guaranteed that -- given a non-const argument -- it would still behave the same?

Yes, I know proper practice is to include the header, but for the sake of this question, I am assuming that isn't an option.

Comment: In your proposed signature how do parameter names resolve?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. There are no named parameters in C. (but they can serve the human reader) BTW there are `;` missing from your *prototypes*

Comment: @RamblinRose - The parameter names aren't necessary.

Comment: @wildplasser - The point is the dropping of const void* to void*. Thanks for the suggestion about the semicolons.

Comment: I added parameter names to my new declaration, just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, that would work. But, conversely, with the _real_ definition of: `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)` and the _bogus_ definition of `size_t fread(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)` could be problematic with: `buf[5] = 20; fread(buf,1,20,stream); x = buf[5];` It might tell the optimizer that it can _reorder_ this as: `buf[5] = 20; x = buf[5]; fread(buf,1,20,stream);` because it would assume that `fread` will _not_ change the buffer, resulting in UB.

Comment: @KevinHarrison yes indeed

Comment: @CraigEstey - To make sure I understand you correctly: you can drop const modifiers, but you cannot add them.

Comment: Modifiers are sidewheels, they don't change the generated code, only the warnings and errors. (except, maybe, for noalias)

Comment: @KevinHarrison I see that you asked also about `restrict`. You can't qualify a type that is not a pointer with restrict, like `fwrite(restrict void * ptr)` will not compile. But `void func(void * ptr)` and `void func(void * restrict ptr)` and like `void func(void * restrict const ptr)` and any other combination are all fine and the same function.

Comment: @wildplasser using the wrong modifier as in the question causes undefined behaviour, so the generated code may change (or the program be rejected). But your comment is still incorrect for other cases, the compiler might take advantage of information provided by qualifiers .(and must do so in the case of `volatile`) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C 2018 6.7.6.3 15 says:

> For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types. Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; corresponding parameters shall have compatible types…

So, we see that for `fwrite` in `size_t fwrite(const void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);` to be compatible with `fwrite` in `size_t fwrite(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);`, `const void *` must be compatible with `void *`.

C 2018 6.7.6.1 2 says:

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

Since `const *` and `void *` are not identically qualified, they are not compatible, so the two `fwrite` declarations above are not compatible.

Furthermore, C 2018 6.5.2.2 9 says, about calling a function:

> If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined.

That means, if `fwrite` is called using one of the declarations above but is defined with the other declaration (with the semicolon replaced with a block implementing the function), the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

### Note

C 2018 6.7.6.3 15 includes:

> … (In the determination of type compatibility and of a composite type, each parameter declared with function or array type is taken as having the adjusted type and each parameter declared with qualified type is taken as having the unqualified version of its declared type.)

This does not apply in the `fwrite` declaration. It says that if a parameter is, for example, qualified with `const`, that is ignored for determining compatibility. So `const size_t size` would be effectively the same as `size_t size`. However, in `const void *ptr`, the parameter is not `const`-qualified; it is a pointer to a `const`-qualified type. The parameter `ptr` would be `const`-qualified if it were `void * const ptr` or `const void * const ptr`.